# using javascript modulus to update rows of tiles position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a grid of tiles using `position:absolute` that consists of 5 tiles per row, as I'm not sure how many tiles will ever be present I want to create some javascript that loops through the tiles and dynamically adds the top and left position so:

1st row: top:0; left:0 then 51px then 102px...
2nd row: top:51px; left: 0 then 51px then 102px..
3rd row ...

Im aware I need to use modulus in my loop but I'm really only familiar with picking a 1 item like i%4 == 0 instead of actually influencing full rows?

Can anyone explain how I can achieve this?

JS

```
var list = $('ul').children();

for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {

    console.log(i);
    console.log( list[i] );    

    // first 5 top: 0 left: 0,51,102,153,204
    // second 5 top:51 left: 0,51,102,153,204
    // third 5 top: 102 left: 0,51,102,153,204
    $( list[i] ).css({
        left: i*51        
    });   


}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7TwF/4/

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you use absolute positioning? You can create tiles and float the left, if they exceed the container width, they will be presented on the next line ...

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/Yoeri/88zdA/ with floating elemens.

Comment: i need to position the absolutely as I need to expand some of the tiles on hover without disturbing the other tiles

Comment: sounds lika a good reason to do so :-)

Comment: little hint, take jquery outerWidth(true) of the li-elements instead of 51, when the sizes change, you don't have to keep your javascript in sync with your css attached to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
left: (i % 5) * 51
top: Math.floor(i / 5) * 51
```

This will get the remainder of the division by 5, and multiply that with 51. The top value is needs to be truncated, Javascript has no operator for the euclidean division.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = $('ul').children();

for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    $( list[i] ).css({
        top: (parseInt(i / 5) * 51) + "px",
        left: ((i % 5) * 51) + "px"        
    });   
}
```

Comment: hi, the top position of this is a little weird 2nd tile gets top:10.20000000000000001px?

Comment: You are right. I forgot to add parseInt. I've edited my post.